# Dropbox integration using oAuth2 Url in React Native Android is not working with handleOpenUrl

Tags: android, react-native, dropbox

I have successfully integrated dropbox oAuth2 and Writing files to dropbox in react native for iOS. Same code is not working for Android.

I am using  oAuth Url and handleOpenUrl in react native  to read the incoming links in Android.

It opens the Dropbox website with the OAuthUrl and authorizes the user. In  Dropbox website when it asks permission to access files and folders, when we tap on "Allow" it doesn't open my app.

So the control is not passed back and it doesn't call `handleOpenUrl` method. Not sure what I am missing.

I also tried with below method:

```
Linking.getInitialURL().then((url) => {
        if (url) {
          console.log('Initial url is: ' + url);
          this.navigate(url);
      }
```

But this gives url  comes as undefined.

In `AndroidManifest.XML` file I added the intent filter and permissions :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

 <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:scheme="https"
          android:host="www.dropbox.com" />

        <data android:scheme="https"
          android:host="www.dropbox.com/oauth2/authorize" />
<!-- Oauth2 redirect url set when dropbox app is created --> 
        <data android:scheme="com.companyname.appname.oauth"
          android:host="oauthredirect" />
      </intent-filter>
```

In Activity tag added  android:launchMode="singleTask".

**Below is the code snippet of React Native code :**

```
export class DropboxAuthorize implements Authorize {
constructor() {

    this._handleOpenURL = this._handleOpenURL.bind(this);
  }

  // Authorize with Dropbox. Uses the device's browser to work through the Dropbox
  // OAuth 2 process, eventually recording a token and account ID if successful.
  public authorize(): Promise<void> {
    console.log("Authorization starting...");
    // Generate a random string for Dropbox's state param.
    // This helps us be sure a deep link into the app is indeed related to the request
    // we made to Dropbox.
    const stateValue = Math.random().toString();
     console.log("authorize stateValue",stateValue);
    // Open the Dropbox authorization page in the device browser
    return Linking.openURL(
      [
        'https://www.dropbox.com/oauth2/authorize',
        "?response_type=token",
        `&client_id=${DROPBOX.OAUTH_CLIENT_ID}`,
        `&redirect_uri=${DROPBOX.OAUTH_REDIRECT_URI}`,
        `&state=${stateValue}`
      ].join("")
    )
      .catch(err =>
        console.error(
          "An error occurred trying to open the browser to authorize with Dropbox:",
          err
        )
      )
      .then(() => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          const handleOpenURL = (event: { url: string }) => {
            console.log("event", event);
            this._handleOpenURL(event, stateValue)
              .then(() => {
                resolve();
              })
              .catch(reason => {
                reject(reason);
              })
              .then(() => {
                // "Finally" block
                // Remove deep link event listener
                Linking.removeEventListener("url", handleOpenURL);
                return;
              });

          };
           console.log("Hi there");
          // Add deep link event listener to catch when Dropbox sends the user back to the app.
          Linking.addEventListener("url", handleOpenURL);
        });
      });
  }

  private _handleOpenURL(
    event: { url: string },
    stateValue: string
  ): Promise<void> {
    console.log("Deep link event!", event);
    console.log("State Value",stateValue);
    const queryStringResult = event.url.match(/\#(.*)/);
    if (queryStringResult === null || queryStringResult.length < 2) {
      return Promise.reject(
        "Did not receive a query string as part of this deep link!"
      );
    }

    const [, queryString] = queryStringResult;
    const parsedQueryString = shittyQs(queryString);
    console.log ("parsedQueryString",parsedQueryString);
    if (parsedQueryString.error) {
      // There was an error!
      const errorCode = parsedQueryString.error;
      const errorDescription = parsedQueryString.error_description;

      console.error("Dropbox OAuth error! code:", errorCode);
      console.error("Error description:", errorDescription);

      return Promise.reject(
        `Could not authorize with Dropbox. Code: ${errorCode}`
      );
    }

      if (parsedQueryString.state){
        if (stateValue !== parsedQueryString.state) {
          // This value must match! This is a security feature of Dropbox's OAuth impl
          return Promise.reject("State parameter DID NOT MATCH!");
        }
      }
    // Otherwise: not an error!
    const accessToken = parsedQueryString.access_token;
    const accountId = parsedQueryString.account_id;

    // Persist accessToken and accountId
    return AsyncStorage.setItem(DROPBOX.ACCESS_TOKEN_STORAGE_KEY, accessToken)
      .then(() => {
     /*    return AsyncStorage.setItem(DROPBOX.ACCOUNT_ID_STORAGE_KEY, accountId);
      })
      .then(() => { */
        console.log(
          "Dropbox OAuth authorization success! Access Token:",
          accessToken
        );
       /*  console.log(
          "Dropbox OAuth authorization success! Account ID:",
          accountId
        ); */
        return;
      });
  }
```

Let me know if any alternative method is available to read the incoming links.

Comment: thanks @halfer shall keep that in mind.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue by creating a redirect Url in my dropbox apps : company_name://open
Then in AndroidManifest.xml file i  added the scheme and host as below :

Comment: hi @Pawan did you get the Dropbox's accessToken?

Comment: Sorry, the whole example is missing in your answer. Can you please share it? Thanks

Comment: Never mind, I have read the documentation :) https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/deep-linking